# Attempt to get length of null array when trying to get a file name into Recycler View

Tags: java, android, file

I'm having a problem when trying to get a filename and putting it into my recycler view.

I do have the user permissions and Legacy External Storage set on true so I think this is not the problem here.

I made 3 rows to check if the code does anything.

If I try to fetch the contents of a folder that does not exist it returns 3 rows in my view

"Test Line"

"/storage/emulated/0"

"storage/emulated/0/Test"

but as soon as I create the folder "Test" the app crashes when trying to fetch the folder contents no matter if there are files in it or if its empty and it tells me "Attempt to get length of null array"

I checked many other threads that are kind of similar but I only found people whose problem was that they didn't have updated their Manifest file.

Here is my code for the MainActivity.

Help would be much apreciated and thank you for your time!

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<String> arrayFiles = new ArrayList<String>();

        ArrayList<ExampleItem> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();

        File fldrKleb = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        File myKleb = new File(fldrKleb, "Test");
        if (myKleb.length() > 0)
            for (File f : myKleb.listFiles()) {
                if (f.isFile()) {
                    String kleb = f.getName();

                    for (int i = 0; i < kleb.length(); i++)
                        arrayFiles.add(kleb);

                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayFiles.size(); i++) {
                        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Test" + arrayFiles.get(i), "Date:"));
                    }
                }
            }
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "Test Line", "Date:"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "" + fldrKleb.getPath(), "Date:"));
        exampleList.add(new ExampleItem(R.drawable.ic_android, "" + myKleb.getPath(), "Date:"));

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        mAdapter = new ExampleAdapter(exampleList);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- `File.listFiles` may return null, so always check it.
- `File.list` the same, but lists only local file names, so String, which might be more useful here.
- `File.length` returns the length of a regular file.

  > The return value is unspecified if this pathname denotes a directory.

Tip: one should do

```
    List<String> arrayFiles = new ArrayList<>();
```

Also for parameters and return values use the most general class (resp. interface).

This allows to change implementations, be as strong as possible with your methods.